# Fullpage.js div escapes section

Tags: html, css, fullpage.js

[image]

At first, I have two rows of three divs in my page, as is what I want to use later on in my webpage. However, when I test out 'mobile view', the divs in the section escape the section and flow over into the next section/or part below the section, like so:

[image: image2]

Any way to make the sections 'bigger' so that I can just scroll down and view the divs below the other three divs, and then get to the next section? Or some other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any way to make the sections 'bigger' so that I can just scroll down
>   and view the divs below the other three divs, and then get to the next
>   section? Or some other solution?

Only if you disabled the `autoScrolling` feature of fullpage.js whenever that happens.

You could use the `responsive` option as [in this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/responsive.html) and then possibly combine it by adding the class `fp-auto-height` to your sections so they will have `height: auto` as explained [here in the docs](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#creating-smaller-sections).

This last step of adding the class, you would have to do it with jQuery or Javascript by yourself, as the plugin doesn't provide a way to add it dynamically under certain width.